# Custom Dash style in OpenLayers 3?

Tags: openlayers, style, rendering

I know that it is possible to make a line or polygon with dashed stroke. It can be done with the following way, for example:

```
    var myStyle = new ol.style.Style ({
      stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
      color: 'rgba(221, 99, 0, 0.5)',
      width: 3,
      lineDash: [40,10] // <- [dashLength, dashSpace]
    });
```

I would like to know it is possible to put a pattern or a text (as a pattern) in the stroke drawn, in OpenLayers 3. I painted a picture which represents what I would like:

[image: Dash line with text pattern]

I tried to look for some options [here](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.6.0/apidoc/ol.style.Stroke.html) but there is no any.

If it is can't be done with the standard OL3 libary, are there any external library for this matter?

I tried to look for some solution over this site but I could not find any. I am of the opinion that this "task" can only be done by making a "hook" in the canvas renderer of OpenLayers 3.

Comment: Can you resolve your problem?

Comment: @morteza malvandi Unfortunately I could not solve the problem... :/